# How can I use Alamofire to add auth header to each request, and do something if the response is 401?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How can I use Alamofire networking framework to add Authorization header to each request, and also do a check whether the response was 401 from the server, so that I can do logic accordingly, and also present some kind of a login view.

Would I need to create some kind of an HttpService class that wraps Alamofire requests? Or is there a more built in way?

Comment: take a look at https://learnwithmehere.blogspot.in/2016/09/simple-effective-and-robust-network.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per to your requirement, I would personally prefer to have a intermediate class for calling methods of Alamofire.

For that you can add auth header on each web service call.

Here is the following example for Intermediate class.

- WebClient.swift

  ```
  class WebClient: SessionManager {

  static let sharedManager = WebClient()

  func responseRequest(_ url: String, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameter: Parameters? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding, header: HTTPHeaders? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DefaultDataResponse) -> Void) -> Void {

      self.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameter, encoding: encoding, headers: header).response { response in
          completionHandler(response)
      }

  }   }
  ```

You can modify above class as per requirement or you can directly pass header in request method for each webservice call.

Comment: What is the SessionManager that you inherit from?

Answer (score 0):

Adding authorization headers for HTTP Basic Auth and checking the status code is fairly easy:

```
Alamofire
  .request(...)
  .authenticate(user: "username", password: "password")
  .response { response in 
    if let status = response.response?.statusCode, status == 401 {
         // got a 401 response
    }
  }
```